# can two seperate organizations on the same business network be distinguished?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Currently, I have two organizations on the same business network (org1 and org2) and I have different roles for participants set up in the model file as

```
participant Mailer identified by workerid {
  o String workerid
}
participant Processor identified by wid {
  o String wid
}
```

is there a way to add a rule in the permissions file so that only admins from org1 can create Mailers and only admins from org2 can create Processors. something along the lines of

```
rule enableOrg1ToCreateMailers {
  description: "Enable admin from org 1 to create Mailers"
  participant(t): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
  operation: CREATE
  resource: "demonetwork1.Mailer"
  condition: (t.organization.getidentifier() == "org1")
  action: ALLOW
}
```

Comment: Is the above `acl` working? If not, what error are you getting?

Comment: I have not tried the above acl, I wrote it as an example to see if there is anyway to specify organization in the acl. I could not find anything in their documentation for acl to specify organisations.

Answer (score 1):

your rule would probably be something more like this (as 'organization' is not an attribute of that 'system' admin class):

```
rule enableOrg1ToCreateMailers {
  description: "Enable admin from org 1 to create Mailers"
  participant(t): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
  operation: ALL  // (CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE)
  resource: "demonetwork1.Mailer"
  condition: (t.getIdentifier() == "org1admin")
  action: ALLOW
}
```

You might prefer to define the participant instance in something like `org.acme.mynetwork.orgadmin` (with an 'organization' field you add in the model)  and then use that eg.

```
participant(t): "org.acme.mynetwork.orgadmin"
```

and your original condition above.

Its more efficient to provide the Organization (like you've done) as an attribute of a business network participant class involved in creating business network resources so the ACL is checked immediately...rather than derive it from another source as it were. I added 'ALL' only - if the same business network admins are allowed to perform the other CRUD operations on such resources etc (ie more than 'CREATE' operation etc).

Finally, an example (albeit a slightly more complex condition, nevertheless can give you the same principles) elsewhere is shown here as a useful reference point : [Includes function in ACL condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459155/includes-function-in-acl-condition)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of the ACL language, you will find this passage describing the `condition`:

> Condition is a Boolean JavaScript expression over bound variables. Any JavaScript expression that is legal within an `if(...)` expression may be used here. JavaScript expressions used for the condition of an ACL rule can refer to JavaScript utility functions in a script file. This allows a user to easily implement complex access control logic, and re-use the same access control logic functions across multiple ACL rules.

So it seems to me the right path is to experiment with this feature and find out how you can inject javascript based logic into the ACL file.