# Hyperledger Composer access controls

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In my network, the relevant part of the model is as below.

```js
asset Farm identified by farmId{
   o String farmId
   o String FarmLocation
   o String[] images optional 
   o String[] waterSources
   o String[] nearFactories
   o String otherDescription optional
   o Certification certification 
   --> Stakeholder owner
   o String[] farmers 
 }
 
 participant Stakeholder identified by stakeholderId{
  o String stakeholderId
  o String name
  o Address address
  o String email optional 
  o String telephone optional
  o Certification certification optional 
  o String[] images optional
  o Company company
  o String username
  o String password 
  o StakeholderType type
  o String description optional 
  o String authPerson 
  o String vehicleNo optional
  o DistType distributionType optional
  o String branchNo optional 
}
```

In Farm asset, I store relevant Farmer participants' identifiers as a string array under farmers attribute. I want to allow only the farmers whose IDs include in this array, to access the Farm asset. To achieve that I tried below access rule. But It does not seem working as expected.

```js
rule FarmersHasAccessToTheirFarms {
    description: "Allow all participants full access to their assets"
    participant(p): "org.ucsc.agriblockchain.Stakeholder"
    operation: ALL
    resource(r): "org.ucsc.agriblockchain.Farm"
    condition: (p.type == "FARMER" && p.stakeholderId in r.farmers)
    action: ALLOW
}
```

How to achieve this requirement? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `.some` function - someone has already posted an answer here -> [Includes function in ACL condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459155/includes-function-in-acl-condition) that is similar to what you want to achieve.

eg something like

```
condition: (p.type == "FARMER" && (r.farmers.some(function (checkstake) {
        return checkstake === p.stakeholderId;  
    } ))
```